# Call function when control is shown

Tags: html, angularjs

I have input control:

```
<input id="someID" class="form-control" type="text" name="SomeData"
data-ng-model="vm.SomeData">
```

and I need to initialize value `vm.SomeData` when user will scroll down to this control. I am new in angular, so not sure is there some event like 'ControlDisplayed'?

Answer (score 0):

```
 //html 
<input id="someID" when-scrolled="vm" class="form-control" type="text" name="SomeData" data-ng-model="vm.SomeData">

//try this directive
app.directive("whenScrolled", function(){
  return {  
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
    // we get a list of elements of size 1 and need the first element
    raw = elem[0];    
    // we load more elements when scrolled past a limit
    elem.bind("scroll", function(){
      if(raw.scrollTop+raw.offsetHeight+5 >= raw.scrollHeight){
           scope.vm.name = 'Nainish Modi';
         // we can give any function which loads more elements into the list
           scope.$apply(attrs.whenScrolled);
         }
       });
      }
    }
 });
```